How to find maximum DC voltage allowable on a Schneider ic60n circuit braker
Looking for a DC disconnect switch for a solar array, Typically what is done in my area is they use a DC rated circuit breaker instead of using a solar disconnect switch (caused a few fires because of these failing).
My problem is these DC “solar” breakers are usually Chinese brands and no from reputable brands (that I can get a hold of) so I'm a bit skeptical on those, I'm probably sure there are good Chinese brands out there, but finding which one is the problem.
Anyway my hope right now is this breaker from Schneider: iC60N series and the datasheet says it's okay to use in a DC network, but my only problem is I do not see a maximum voltage rating especially for DC.
There is though breaking capacity, although breaking capacity is important, I don't really mind having very low breaking capacity as the DC lines are fused, what I really care about is it able to handle 350 V DC (my short circuit voltage).


The breaking capacities seem to indicate a maximum 125 V DC and 450 V AC. If it can handle 450 V AC wont that imply that its internals are able to handle withstand 450 V AC and DC? If current is the problem I can always get a higher Amp rated version as I don't plan on using it as a breaker but rather a disconnect, and the line is fused to a lower rating than the breaker, so there is no problem of an overcurrent.

This question is similar to: Why does a circuit breaker voltage rating differ between AC and DC?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

High voltage DC breakers and switches use special measures to extinguish the arc, magnets for example. There is no chance a 400V AC breaker will survive 350V DC. I use these, they work fine. Note PV panels limit current, so fuses are useful only if you parallel strings and worry about backfeeding into a shorted string.
